# PHP - can't upload files larger than 25MB

Tags: php, jquery, iis, file-upload

I'm fiddling with [BlueImp's jQuery File Upload](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload) script on my own IIS server. The idea is to make a mass file upload system, so that people can upload and store even the largest files (a max. of 500MB per file is what I'm going for).

The script is currently configured like this:

```
$options = array(
    'image_versions' => array(),
    'acceptFileTypes' => '/(\.|\/)(gif|jpe?g|png|avi|mp4|mpg|mkv|mov|wmv|flv)$/i',
    'maxFileSize' => 500 * 1014 * 1024
);
```

Which should allow about every multimedia file extention at a max. of 500MB per file. However, after testing, it appears to be failing as soon as the file size exceeds 10MB. Files larger than that don't get stored.

After some searching, I updated my php.ini settings to some ridiculously high values:

```
post_max_size = 500M
upload_max_filesize = 500M
max_file_uploads = 100
max_execution_time = 5000
max_input_time = 5000
memory_limit = 1024M
```

This partially fixed things. I can upload larger files now. However, it still chokes at files larger than 25MB. Don't think it's the execution time, as it takes only a few seconds to upload 100MB or more on my local network. Running phpinfo() confirms that all the values in php.ini are correctly interpreted (and not overwritten by master values).

Does anyone have any idea what could be causing the large file uploads to fail?

Comment: Do you have any errors in your webserver logs? When you say its failing, do you mean it just stops transferring? or white screen, or just doesn't store with no obvious error?

Comment: It's been some time now I didn't play with IIS and last time was with .NET not with PHP but I'm pretty sure there's a `maxrequestlength` parameter or something like that on IIS to limit the size of your request and that has nothing to do with your PHP settings.

Comment: In nginx server what I have to do is set the desired value for `client_max_body_size` in nginx configuratin. Maybe the same in IIS. Not sure but you can give it a try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider that not only PHP sets limits in regard of file upload, but also IIS does.
According to [this website](http://www.webtrenches.com/post.cfm/iis7-file-upload-size-limits) you can enhance your site upload size limits adding the following to the `web.config` file related to your website:

```
<system.webServer>
    <security>
        <requestFiltering>
            <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="524288000"/>
        </requestFiltering>
    </security>
</system.webServer>
```

This is said to work on IIS7

Comment: Applied the changes and everything works fine now! Thanks a lot!